# Unable to Execute a Query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, select

I want to create an index for my SQL Table Column I have also asked a Question before here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842488/index-similar-records-sql-server

I just need to know that I have created a Query that I want to copy my all data from my existing table to a new table! the query is to be executed using Java Platform!

```
 Statement stat=con.createStatement();
 ResultSet ss;
 String s="Select * INTO log2 FROM log SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ip) basescore from log";
 ss=stat.executeQuery(s);
```

The problem is that it creates a table named log2 as a new table for me and a column basescore WITHOUT any values to be generated! I don't why it is not working with Java because I have tried it with SQL Server Query and it executes Successfully! Please can somebody help me please I will be thankful to him please

Comment: Is your query syntatically correct? Try to run the query on sql server first.

Comment: Query doesn't seem correct. Those are two queries on one single line. Maybe this works from management studio, but in Java I think you should make two queries out of them or put a semicolumn in between.

Comment: yes it is working fine with management studio so it seems like the query is correct enough but unable to done with it using Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to create a new table `log2` with the values from `log` plus the dense rank as `basescore`the query should look like this:

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ip) basescore INTO log2 FROM log
```

If you only want unique rows you can add the `DISTINCT`keyword after `SELECT` (and instead of using `*` you might want to specify the column names in the query).

Comment: I think I am new to SQL and People like you always help others so thanks to you !!! hats off Sir ! so nice of you!